# Why make the difference betwen typedef and defining structure in my case?(See description for what i want)

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, typedef

I am going through the Linux kernel source code. I found following statements,

```
#ifdef CONFIG_REFCOUNT
typedef struct {
        int counter;
} ato_unchecked_t;
#else
typedef int ato_unchecked_t;
#endif
```

What would be the purpose of having a structure with one int member or just 
a typedef'd int like this ?

Comment: So your question is **not** "***What is** the difference between ...*", **but** "***Why make** the difference between ...*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only benefit to having a structure would be if all the code where `CONFIG_REFCOUNT` is defined is designated as user customizable. More fields can be added to the structure that are logically related and used for user specific functionality.

Comment: Your answer make sense

Answer (score 0):

I have understood your question now. It is needed for reference counting - storing number of references to some resource or object. This can be used by garbage collection algorithms. The variable inside the structure stores the count of references. When new reference is created, the variable `count` is incremented and vice versa. For further information refer to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), for example. Preprocessor directive indicates, if this mode is enabled

Comment: I know this, But why we need this?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet uses the pre-processor - if the #define `CONFIG_REFCOUNT` is defined then the structure definition of `ato_unchecked_t` is parsed. If CONFIG_REFCOUNT is not defined the typedef creates the type `ato_unchecked_t` (it's underlying type is int).

In summary the #ifdef guarantees that a definition for type `ato_unchecked_t` exists. One possible definition is a struct and the other definition is an int.

Comment: I know that, But why we need that?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code. I see no advantage in using the struct to store an int. Possibly the #ifdef was required for mods to legacy code or the optional use of some library code.